# Discordpy purging messages from a specific user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently I'm trying to delete messages that are sent by a certain user, however I get the error:

> Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'author'

I'm unsure why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
@client.command()
async def message_test(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):

    def user_filter(message):
        return message.author.id == 627862713242222632

    messages = [m.content async for m in channel.history().filter(user_filter)]
    print(messages)  # prints the list we get from the line above
    me = messages.author == 627862713242222632
    deleted = await channel.purge(limit=100, check=me)
    await channel.send('Deleted {} message(s)'.format(len(deleted)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote doesn't make any sense at all. Here's how to delete 100 messages of a specific user id.

```py
def is_user_message(message):
    return message.author.id == some_user_id

await channel.purge(limit=100, check=is_user_message)
```